# How to install NodeJS project locally without internet connection?

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I have a project which I will have to deploy to client Windows systems where it will not be possible to connect to internet. I currently have a folder in D:\NODE which contains node.exe and npm.cmd and a node_modules folder. To be able to run node from command line I have added D:\NODE to PATH variable.

I can have most of the modules installed locally inside node_modules of my project. However there's one - node-windows - which needs to be installed globally to work.

Following suggestion below I went to node-windows (installed globally) and packaged it up (`npm pack`), which created a tarball. I have then copied that file with my project and tried to install it on the test machine globally like this: `npm install -g node-windows-0.1.5.tgz`

I can see that it got installed in the global directory. However when I try to                    run the command which uses this module it complains that it cannot find it: `Error: Cannot find module 'node-windows'`

When I list the modules (`npm list -g`) it is clearly there in the list...

What do you think? And thank you.

Comment: There is a better way to do this now by using `npm pack <module_name>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549885/535827

Comment: My answer was deleted as duplicate in this thread, but I found that there is no easy way in 2019 to do this but I did get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744517/101662

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can install packages on a system without internet connection by packing them using built-in functionality in *npm*. This way, the *node modules* will be installed properly.

1. Create a **package.json**.
2. In your **package.json**, list all the modules you need under `bundledDependencies` ([docs on npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies)).
3. Run `npm install` to install your node files before packing.
4. Create a tarball with `npm pack`.
5. Copy the tarball over to the machine without internet connection.
6. Install the modules with `npm install <filename>`.

**Update**

Regarding your comments, it looks like your globally installed *node modules* isn't found.

Try using the `npm link` command ([docs on npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)):

1. `cd yourAppFolder`
2. `npm link node-windows`

Comment: Hello... I'm still having problems - installing the packaged module globally doesn't seem to work :( Please see the updated question. Any thoughts? Thank you...

Comment: I have also tried setting NODE_PATH in the env variables as suggested somewhere else...

Comment: And cleared NPM cache. And checked the package: `npm test -g --verbose node-windows` and its all there...

Comment: I tried this an npm hangs on the target machine at: npm install mytar.1.0.0.tgz fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule COR3Backend@1.0.0 checking installable status

Comment: Does it work with packing from windows and installing on linux?

Comment: I have to change the name of the project before npm install <filename> because it throws an error ```npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "PROJECT" under a package
npm ERR! also called "PROJECT". Did you name your project the same```

Answer (score 9):

1 - In system with internet access install module with this command:

```
npm install [module name]
```

2 - go to %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules[module name]\
(e.g C:\Users\janson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli)
3 - run `npm pack`
4 - this should result in a [module name]-x.y.z.tgz file
5 - run `npm i -g [module name]-x.y.z.tgz` in offline system

Comment: You can run `npm pack <module_name>` to save the package as a tarball in one step.  That is a bit simpler

Comment: Running 5. still seems to want internet access npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/arrivals failed, reason:
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org

Comment: @Oliver, I think it is because it needs to install the dependencies, and it can't connect to the internet, I am having the same problem

Comment: But sees you can get the complete tarball here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/releases