# Download a package from npm as a tar (not installing it to a module)

Tags: npm

Is there some URL from which I can download a given package from npm (as a tarball or something)? I need the exact files that were originally uploaded to npm.

Using `npm install` gets a different, generated package.json for example. I want the exact original set of files that was published.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can use [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) to get the URL to the registry's tarball (in this example for the module `level`):

```
$ npm view level dist.tarball
```

And to download tarball, you can use [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack):

```
$ npm pack level
```

Comment: `npm pack <module_name>` was exactly what I needed to download an npm module from an authenticated registry in the first stage of a dockerfile before copying it to the final stage (which doesn't have access to credentials)

Comment: Just to stress it again, since it is rather unintuitive: `npm pack <package-name>` will indeed download the tarball, despite what you may expect from the naming. No need to use the `npm view` command.

Comment: Is there somehow a way to get the tarball download URL for the previous versions? All these commands seem to work only for the latest version.

Comment: @VincentiusDaniel you can specify the version of the package as in `npm view react@16.0.0 dist.tarball` which yields `https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-16.0.0.tgz` despite the latest version being `react@17.0.2` as of now.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. `npm pack` also downloads it directly to your `pwd`

Comment: this would be a great answer if it was obvious that `level` was the package name.

Comment: In my case, I was looking for how to find out the package checksum (sha512, not sha1). With the help of this answer, managed to do it like so: `npm pack --dry-run --json 'package@version' | sed -rn '/"integrity":/{s/.*"([^"]+)"[^"]*/\1/;p;q}'`

Answer (score 24):

If you need to get the tarball **without having npm installed**, you can fetch the package information using `curl` and use `jq` to get the right information from the JSON:

```
curl https://registry.npmjs.org/PACKAGE-NAME/ \
    | jq '.versions[."dist-tags".latest].dist.tarball'
```

This is for instance useful if you're building a Docker container that requires one npm package, and don't want to install npm just for that.

Answer (score 22):

Running `npm pack PACKAGE_NAME` will download a tarball of any package on npm.

To extract it, just run `tar -xzf DOWNLOADED_FILE.tgz`

#### Example:

```
npm pack react
```

then extract:

```
tar -xzf react-16.6.3.tgz
```

Answer (score 21):

Just run the command

```
npm view [package name] dist.tarball
```

It will return a tar url.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can `npm install <git remote URL>` to download the full repository into `node_modules`. This will be directly from the repository's host, rather than via npm, though. See [the `npm install` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I asked for. I want the files that were uploaded to npm, not the source files on github (they might not even be on github). And I'm not trying to 'install' them in node_modules. I just want to download a tar of whatever files were originally published to npm.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I should have asked for clarification via comment.