How to install a node module in Dockerfile without package.json?
I want to create a Docker image container that just runs a simple javascript file that just requires one module (aws-sdk). How can I install just this one module? Can I do it without copying a package.json file into the docker container?
My Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM node:14

# Install aws-sdk
RUN npm install aws-sdk

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the local js script to the working directory in remote container
COPY myScript.ts ./
# The structure now looks like '/usr/src/app/myScript.ts'

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "myScript.ts"]

But when building my Docker container, I get this error:
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install aws-sdk" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


You can; you probably need to RUN npm install after you switch WORKDIR; but I'm not sure how you'd develop and debug this without running equivalent manual commands on the host, and maintaining a package.json (and package-lock.json) is usually better practice.  The error message you quote just essentially says "it didn't work"; is there more to the error than that?

This sounds like XY problem. You can download a package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530978 , but this won't download nested dependencies. You need to have package.json in order for node_modules to be correctly installed. You can use npm init -y && npm i aws-sdk to create it from scratch, but it makes more sense to just maintain package.json. Btw this doesn't look like " a simple javascript file", it's .ts that requires typescript or tsx to be installed too

This works for me:
# Stage 1: Install dependencies
FROM node:14 as builder

WORKDIR /tmp

# Install aws-sdk
RUN npm init -y && npm install aws-sdk

# Stage 2: Build the final image
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the aws-sdk module from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /tmp/node_modules ./node_modules

# Copy your script
COPY myScript.ts ./

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "myScript.ts"]


This approach ensures that only the required dependencies are installed in the final image without needing a package.json file.
Stage 1) Install dependencies: This stage installs the aws-sdk module in a temporary working directory.
Stage 2) Build the final image: This stage sets up the final image, copying the installed node_modules directory from the first stage, and then copies your JavaScript file into the working directory.
Then you can build your docker image :
docker build -t my-node-app .

To run the container :
docker run my-node-app

