# How do you use tfs-cli in a disabled network environment?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Our TFS build server does not have access to the internet. After getting node.js installed next I tried to install `tfx-cli`. using the command:
`npm install -g tfx-cli`

As far as I can tell, now it wants to download dependencies required. It looks like a whole web of dependencies - nuget style. Am I expected to set up an internal npm server with the dozens of dependencies required, becoming an expert on node.js and npm  - just so I can add some custom commands to our TFS server?

Is there a version of tfs-cli I can get that includes all dependencies ?

Comment: Are you looking for https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli?

Comment: I already have it. Try the install command on a machine with no internet...it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just happened to come across your question. Hopefully this will help others.

Although I haven't tried it myself, there do seem to be ways of installing NPM packages offline. [Here's one Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251537/523347) that may get you pointed in the right direction. Another solution I've seen recommended is [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox).

Comment: Hi there, ty to help :) - but when you do not _really_ answer question a comment would be prefere, also only providing links is not a valid answer but could be a helpful comment.

Comment: @Arount Ah, thanks for letting me know. I'll delete this answer and make it a comment instead!

Comment: Well, nevermind. I don't have enough rep to comment on the question :(

Comment: well, i think this is ok - no worries, if your answer needs to be closed trust the SO community will do it (huhu)