# How to install React without command line

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, frontend

I need to install Node.js then React but with out command line, I want to develop some thing in react on offline PC , so I can't install React.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install NodeJS project locally without internet connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250805/how-to-install-nodejs-project-locally-without-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be if you create a react project on a PC with internet connection and copy the node modules to the PC without internet connection. That way you should have the react package (and other packages).

Give me feedback if it's working.

Comment: Thank you Amel. I think it is a good idea , but how can I have react package or where can I find it?

Comment: You can install on your PC with internet connection the react package with a package manager. (npm, yarn, ...). Because you told that you are going to use Node.js, then you will probably use the package manager npm (I think you get both installed together).
Then you can easily install the react package with: ```npm i react``` [source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react). Now you can copy the node modules to the PC without internet connection.

P.S. With package managers you can easily install every package you want and they are very very common to use.

Comment: Another option might be to find a small project on GitHub, which uses React and copy their node modules folder. I bet there are a couple of React Tutorials which you can use.