# npm install Angular-cli not working on CentOS7 without Internet

Tags: npm, virtual-machine, angular-cli, centos7

How to install *Angular CLI* on *CentOS7 vm*?

The machine doesn't have an internet connection.
I can download the required files to a Windows machine and transfer those files to the *CentOS7 virtual machine* using `winscp`.

Please any advises how can I proceed?
I installed *nodeJS* as well. Please see the Error Messages below while trying:

`npm install -g @angular/cli@ll`

[Snip of Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cuOa.png)

Comment: answere here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251537/7149835